# Custom javascript code for default form (NewForm.aspx) of a custom list not working for mobile view

Tags: 2013, javascript, mobile

I have some css and jquery customizations that need to be done before a NewForm.aspx of a custom list is rendered to the client. The changes work fine for a regular PC/Desktop view, but not available when in Mobile view. I have tried customization both using a script editor webpart and JSLink, but to no effect. I don't want to simply disable mobile view for the whole site just to resolve this issue. How can I make the customization work on mobile view?

Answer (score 2):

Customizing fields in mobile view is little bit different from "normal" view. I found out that JSLink functions will not hit; you need to override `FieldRenderingMobileWebControl` property in your `FieldType.cs`, and create your own `YourFieldTypeMobileControl.cs` inherited from `SPMobileBaseFieldControl`.

So, first, in your `FieldType.cs` you should add overriding:

```
public override SPMobileBaseFieldControl  FieldRenderingMobileWebControl
{
   get
   {
      SPMobileBaseFieldControl fieldControl = new YourFieldTypeMobileControl();
      fieldControl.FieldName = this.InternalName;

      return fieldControl;
   }
}
```

Second, you need new class `YourFieldTypeMobileControl.cs`:

```
public class YourFieldTypeMobileControl: SPMobileBaseFieldControl
{        
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        //Always hit for ListView, NewForm, EditForm, DisplayForm
        //If 'ListView': ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display
        //If 'NewForm': ControlMode = SPControlMode.New and then call CreateControlForNew 
        //If 'EditForm': ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit and then call CreateControlForEdit
        //If 'DisplayForm': ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display and then call CreateControlForDisplay

        base.CreateChildControls();           
    }

    protected override System.Web.UI.Control CreateControlForDisplay()
    {
       Label info = new Label();
       info.Text = "Custom field DISPLAY pattern for mobile view";
       return info;
    }

    protected override System.Web.UI.Control CreateControlForNew()
    {
       Label info = new Label();
       info.Text = "Custom field NEW pattern for mobile view";
       return info;
    }

    protected override System.Web.UI.Control CreateControlForEdit()
    {
       Label info = new Label();
       info.Text = "Custom field EDIT pattern for mobile view";
       return info;
    }

}
```

Put your own code in `CreateChildControlFor...` methods to render your functionality.

All info about mobile field rendering I found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862011(v=office.14).aspx. This link is for SP2010, but it also works in SP2013, I've check it.

Comment: Thank you @Olga! but this is not a VS project. I was hoping to make changes from the web interface or Sharepoint Designer. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunally, I failed to fire custom JS functions in mobile views. Looks like SP mobile pages renders on-the-fly from /LAYOUTS/Mobile/... , so we have very limited possibilities to modify them :(